# Find Address and Sum Address Values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a search in my sheet to find a Project Number. After I find it, I'll need to select 14 rows below its address and copy to another sheet. I can find the address were my search was, but I can't select the rows I need. Here's a part of my code

```
If opcao = True Then
    For i = 1 To 200
        If ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = valor_busca Then
            correto = ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Address
            Debug.Print correto, correto_1
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: when you say 14 rows, do you need the entire range up to 14 rows beneath the cell or just the 14th row?

Comment: Hello Scott! I need the entire range up to 14 rows.

Comment: use the `.Resize` method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `.EntireRow`  Something like this:

```
ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Select
```

If you need to select multiple rows, try `.Range`  Something like:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(i + 1, 1), ws.Cells(i + 14, 20)).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.Resize` method. So

`ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(14, 1).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'assumes straight paste`.

You can change the Sheet and Range to paste to as needed.

Comment: This did the trick for the 14 rows! Thanks for replying my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   If opcao = True Then
        For i = 1 To 200
            If ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = valor_busca Then
                Set source = ws.Range(ws.Rows(i + 1), ws.Rows(i + 14))
                source.Select '... or source.Copy (dest)...
                exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
```